# WordPress user actions log

Tags: php, wordpress, logging

I want to log every action that the users do. What's the best way to do this and why? Using `Custom post types` to insert every action as a new post or using `user_meta` and save details in a multidimensional array? The data would look like this:

```
array(
    array(
        'type' => 'comment',
        'time' => 1416335275,
        'comment_id' => 210
    ),
    array(
        'type' => 'post'
        'time' => 1416335275,
        'post_id' => 450
    ),
    array(
        'type' => 'visited'
        'visit_type' => 'page',
        'time' => 1416335275,
        'page_id' => 378
    ),
    // ... etc.
)
```

I don't ask how to do this, just what do you think is the best way to store that data.

Comment: Try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/aryo-activity-log/

Comment: @Len_D, OK, I don't need a plugin, because what I do will be a part of a plugin itself, and it does not need to have dependencies. But I want to say thank you for the link, it will be a good inspiration for me and looks like a decent responce to my question, since it uses CPT. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Relevant question: Why in the world would you want to do this?

OK, well to answer this is a generalized sense, Wordpress is a program that interfaces a database with HTTP requests. So you'd have to capture the content of each HTTP request, and probably filter that through requests that contain logged in users versus not logged in users. To be really specific you'd also have to capture the state of the database at each intersection! Sounds like a nightmare.

Probably you have something much more specific in mind than: "I want to log every action that the users do."

The best way to store data relevant to a user, is via the user meta system. For example:

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta
```